# 5V output switching with WEMOS D1 mini + MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, esp8266

I have a WEMOS D1 mini board which I power with a 5V power supply. I need to switch 5V outputs with a few hundred mA load, so I use AO3400 N-channel MOSFET-s. My schematics are the following:

[image]

However, when I power the circuit, my outputs are all powered, their voltages are between 4-500mV and 4-5V, despite the fact that the gate-source voltage of the MOSFET-s are 0V.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you did not swap the drain with a source terminal? Also, can you measure the output voltage at a LOW state in WEMOS D1 board.

Comment: The problem persists even if I remove the WEMOS D1 from my prototype PCB completely and only connect the 5V input. The MOSFETs legs are connected like on the datasheet (http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/ao3400.pdf). Single top leg (drain) goes to output, bottom left (gate) goes to the WEMOS D1, and bottom right (source) is ground. Continuity testing shows these connections are OK. Interestingly, there is about 300k resistance between the output ground and input ground.

Comment: Where did you buy the MOSFETs?

Comment: But did you remove the pull-down resistors also?  Try to short the gates directly to gnd.

Comment: I did remove the resistors (and the diodes). The problem is the same even with having only the DC input and the MOSFET. I have output voltage even when the Gate terminal is shorted to ground directly.

Comment: @SamGibson i bought them from a local electronics component webshop. From what I can tell, they have a "A09T" marking on them, for which the only relevant Google result is the AO3400.

Comment: @nXu  If the Gate is shorted to ground the output of the FET should be high (no current flow). 

If the Gate is connected to a positive voltage then the FET will turn on (current flow). To get sensible readings from the output you would need some form of load connected. You won't get good results measuring the output with no load.

Comment: @nXu - Thanks for the updates. "*i bought them from a local electronics component webshop*" Based on that and your recent measurements ("*I have output voltage even when the Gate terminal is shorted to ground directly.*") I have written an answer.

Comment: You shouldn't remove those resistors. Put it back or short all the gates to ground. And see the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although parts of some of your descriptions have been a little unclear, your recent statement was:

> I have output voltage even when the Gate terminal is shorted to ground directly.

This *only* leaves faulty / damaged (e.g. by ESD) / counterfeit MOSFETs (or perhaps a problem with your PCB or other physical construction) as possible causes.

You could edit the question to add photos of your physical hardware, in case that shows something of interest. But the first thing I would do, is to get a suitable **working, and known genuine** MOSFET, and repeat your test.

Based on your information, I believe your MOSFETs are either not the type you believe, or are faulty / damaged in some way.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried some BSS138s I have laying around and everything seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

> However, when I power the circuit, my outputs are all powered, their
>   voltages are between 4-500mV and 4-5V, despite the fact that the
>   gate-source voltage of the MOSFET-s are 0V.
>
> What could be the problem?

I suspect that you are not connecting the appropriate loads to your outputs and you are seeing the effect of drain-source leakage current: -

[image]

If all you have connected is a volt meter then the 1 uA flowing will certainly be enough to produce the effect you are seeeing. Try putting a 1 kohm resistor across the load terminals - it should result in maybe a millivolt shown on your meter maximum.

Comment: Thank you. While it was not the problem, it helped me to test the circuit with other MOSFETs.